# Google API that allows access to account security (re: 2-factor auth)

Tags: api, google-api, two-factor-authentication

I am well aware of the security implications of this, so much so that I'm betting it doesn't exist, so before you call me crazy, that's why I'm asking.

I got really tired of having only my phone on me and installing a new app/whatever and finding myself needing to suddenly create a new application-specific password on the fly, and having to navigate Google's decidedly non-mobile-friendly security page to do that.  I want to create an app of some kind that allows me to generate an application-specific password, whether by text or an Android app itself or something else.  As I see it, there are two options here:

1. Use some Google Account Security API (if it exists) to create the application-specific password
2. Do scraping-type behavior (with proper credentials, of course) to automate its creation.  I *really* don't want to do this.

Does anyone know (a) if this type of API exists, or (b) if there are any other ways to go about doing this?  This app would be published on Github for self-hosting, obviously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official API to generate application-specific passwords.

I've solved this myself by doing a couple of things:

1) printing out the QR Code for the account that can be scanned by the Authenticator app in order to generate codes. I keep it secured in my desk. This allows me to reformat my phone without needing to turn two-step off each time.

2) use the browser sign-in for my Android device. When adding a Google account to an Android phone, just before the screen where you enter your username and password, click the menu button (or 3 dots on the screen if you have no menu button) and choose Browser sign-in. This allows you to login to an Android device with your username, real password and verification code rather than an application specific password.

This saves me from needing to generate application-specific passwords 95% of the time.

Jay

Comment: You've mentioned two very specific situations though--I'm looking to find a way to generate application-specific passwords for _other_ applications, not just the normal Google Android account association.  Unless you mean that you could do that to avoid even using application-specific passwords for other apps' logins, but I haven't seen that kind of functionality available.

Comment: Can you provide more details about the applications you are using that require application-specific passwords?

Comment: Let's say, for example, that I'm adding Gmail to my IFTTT account.  The truth is, it doesn't really matter, since my goal for this app isn't just to avoid having to create application-specific passwords for my phone--I would like to be able to use it so that if I'm on some other random computer, I can simply generate myself some application-specific passwords from my app rather than having to log in to my Google Account on that computer, use the Authenticator app to finish logging me in, and _then_ go create an application-specific password and use it.

Comment: You should not enter application-specific passwords on untrusted computers. Regardless, there is no way to programmatically generate application-specific passwords.

Comment: It was just an example.  Regardless, there being no way to programmatically generate application-specific passwords was the answer to the question I was originally asking above.

Comment: I am using a bitcoin API that requires 2 factor. is it possible somehow to get 2factor programatically